# How to Validate Time in decimal using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

User input time in the decimal format.

like

- 0.00 `//Incorrect`
- 1.54 `//Correct value`
- 1.60 `//Incorrect value`
- 1.59 `//correct value`

I have tried to make a regular expression function but it is showing incorrect for all values

```
var regex = /^[0-9]\d*(((,?:[1-5]\d{3}){1})?(\.?:[0-9]\d{0,2})?)$/;
 if (args.Value != null || args.Value != "") {
    if (regex.test(args.Value)) {
        //Input is valid, check the number of decimal places
        var twoDecimalPlaces = /\.\?:[1-5]\d{2}$/g;
        var oneDecimalPlace = /\.\?:[0-9]\d{1}$/g;
        var noDecimalPlacesWithDecimal = /\.\d{0}$/g;

        if (args.Value.match(twoDecimalPlaces)) {

            //all good, return as is
            args.IsValid = true;
            return;
        }
        if (args.Value.match(noDecimalPlacesWithDecimal)) {
            //add two decimal places
            args.Value = args.Value + '00';
            args.IsValid = true;
            return;
        }
        if (args.Value.match(oneDecimalPlace)) {
            //ad one decimal place
            args.Value = args.Value + '0';
            args.IsValid = true;
            return;
        }
        //else there is no decimal places and no decimal
        args.Value = args.Value + ".00";
        args.IsValid = true;
        return;
    } else
        args.IsValid = false;
} else
    args.IsValid = false;
```

Comment: Your regex is more complex than your test case would indicate? Why a regex at all? Split on `.`, check the bounds, parseInt() and check the numeric range, convert to string adding a `0` if needed.

Comment: 24hr format or 12hr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to do working with a number:

```
var time = (+args.Value).toFixed(2); // convert to float with 2 decimal places
if (time === args.Value) {
    // it's a valid number format
    if (time !== 0.0 && time < 24) {
        // the hours are valid
        if (time % 1 < 0.6) {
            // the minutes are valid
        }
    }
}
```

You can collapse all that up into a nice one-liner:

```
if (time === args.Value && time !== 0.0 && time < 24 && time % 1 < 0.6) {
}
```

and even a boolean/ternary

```
var valid = time === args.Value && time !== 0.0 && time < 24 && time % 1 < 0.6;
alert( time === args.Value && time !== 0.0 && time < 24 && time % 1 < 0.6 ? 'valid' : 'invalid' );
```

Comment: hey joe, your explanation is quite well. but i thing i need to do is instead of 60 its .60 as you have taken the module and then remainder is obtain. I debug and check different values its like in the format 0.25 0.89 0.66 0.59 etc. By the way thanks for the reply

Comment: Oh that's a good catch - silly mistake :) Updating the post for reference for other people. Glad it helped you